# How to raise an exception from within an 'with' block in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy to create a transaction.  I'm using `with` to take advantage of the auto commit and rollback:

```
with session.begin():
    do_stuff()
```

If an exception is raised, is there anyway to propagate that exception after the auto rollback?

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't be propagated automatically?

Comment: @Barmar presumably `session` has an `except` clause to determine whether it should commit or rollback.  You're depending on it to re-raise the exception.  Or maybe not, now that I think about it a bit more I'm not sure how the mechanics of that would work.

Comment: I'm presuming that it uses  `finally:` for the cleanup actions, not `except:`

Comment: @Barmar It was a long day...I was changing how I started transactions and my unit test was failing because the validations were not being raised....because it was mocked.  The `__exit__` function never raises in the Mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any exception is raised during the body of a `with` statement, the `__exit__` method is immediately called with that exception as an argument. It is up to `__exit__` to then decide whether the exception has been properly handled (by returning a truthy value) or whether it should be re-raised after `__exit__` completes (by returning a non-truthy value).

[`SessionTransaction.__exit__`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/3ab2364e78641c4f0e4b6456afc2cbed39b0d0e6/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L861) only returns `None`, which indicates that any exception that may have been raised in the body of the `with` statement will be raised again.

---

Note that since the "default" return value of any function is `None`,
the default behavior of `__exit__` is to propagate any exceptions. No user-level code is expected to call `__exit__` explicitly or look at its return value, so you really have to do out of your way to return a truthy value and suppress an expression.

---

Also note the description of the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement's semantics:

> The following code:
>
> ```
> with EXPRESSION as TARGET:
>     SUITE
> ```
>
> is semantically equivalent to:
>
> ```
> manager = (EXPRESSION)
> enter = type(manager).__enter__
> exit = type(manager).__exit__ 
> value = enter(manager)
> hit_except = False
>
> try:
>     TARGET = value
>     SUITE 
> except:
>     hit_except = True
>     if not exit(manager, *sys.exc_info()):
>         raise 
> finally:
>     if not hit_except:
>         exit(manager, None, None, None)
> ```

The `__exit__` method is called under one of two mutually exclusive conditions:

1. An exception was raised, in which case it was called in the `except` clause. If it returns false, the caught exception is re-raised.
2. An exception was not raised, in which case it is called in the `finally` block. `hit_except` is ensures that `exit` is not called twice
   if `exit` itself raises an exception in the `except` block.

Comment: This was helpful, it reminded me that this was a unit test and not actually sqlalchemy, and I had mocked `__exit__` to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do anything special.

Context managers created using `with` are roughly equivalent to:

```
try:
    context initialization
    do_stuff()
finally:
    contact cleanup
```

Unlike an `except:` clause, `finally:` doesn't block propagation of the exception. It executes the statements and then continues propagation.